# Checkbox condição isChecked

Tags: android, checkbox

Olá, estou utilizando um CheckBox e gostaria que se ele estivesse Checado, torna-se visivel um Layout. Estou utilizando o código abaixo e só funciona para quando ele é clicado, mas já quero deixá-lo checado. Tentei tirar o código de dentro do .setOnCheckedChangeListener, mas não funcionou.
Alguém sabe o que pode estar acontecendo? Obrigada

```
cbx22.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (cbx22.isChecked()) {
                    layhorario.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    layhorario.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O listener não será chamado se a `CheckBox` foi checado antes de definir o listener. Provavelmente você está checando dentro do layout com `android:checked="true"`. Use `android:checked="false"` no layout e após definir o listener, cheque como `true`:

```
cbx22.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (cbx22.isChecked()) {
            layhorario.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            layhorario.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
});
cbx22.setChecked(true);
```

Note que o listener é só chamado quando o estado muda. Se você precisar do `CheckBox` inicialmente falso, então no layout inicialize como `true` e na activity depois do listener, `setChecked(false)`.

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa já defini-lo como checked, antes mesmo do ChangeListener

Exemplo:

```
cbx22.setSelected(true);
```

Quando ele entrar no ChangeListener já vai estar checado

Comment: Oi eu já estou definindo ele checado, mas aí não funciona. Mesmo assim, eu tenho que desmarcar e checar de novo.